# Parsing Django DateTimeField in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I built my backend API with the Django rest framework in which the model has a DateTimeField.

```py
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I get the data from the API to React I get something like this

```
2019-01-20T19:24:58.674435Z
```

How can I parse this in javascript and convert it to a readable form?

Comment: Which form you want to read?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: You can find documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). More details, depending on what you want to extract and how you want to output, use standard Date [functions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do it through your serializer. Given that you name it ''date'' in your model, you can do the following.

```py
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields='__all__'
```